# Swift Parsing JSON Values to global Array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, parsing

I have been trying to get the below code to return an array of information that can use in a UIPickerView class "title for Rows. The code does not work, I do now that when I run the print script it does return a list of all the values from my JSON values. A sample of parsed JSON. I have been watching YouTube Videos and reading info about this for two evenings now. Any help would be great. Everything I find sends Parsed JSON results to a table view.

```
       {
    date = "2017-05-01";
    "financial_institution" = "Your Neighbourhood C.U.";
    "five_year" = "2.79";
    "four_year" = "3.15";
    key = 86;
    "one_year" = "2.79";
    "six_months" = 0;
    "three_year" = "3.09";
    "two_year" = "2.89";
    "variable_rate" = 0;
}
```

)

```
        func getJSONData()
    {
        let url = URL(string:"")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil {
        print("error")
    }

    else {

        if let mydata = data {

            do {

                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: mydata, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

               print(myJson)

                var lenderName = myJson["financial_institution"]

                for i in lenderName {

                    var lender = "financial_institution"
                    lender += "\(i)"
                    var lenderList = myJson[lender].string as String!

                    lenderNamesArray.append(lenderList)
                }


            }

                catch {
                    // catch error
                }
            }
        }
    }

task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: But according to your response json  **financial_institution** doesn't contain an array object. it's only K-V pair object. so you can't iterate through this object.

Comment: Show the actual JSON instead of some part of it